# Titanium: build error after upgrade to 3.5.0.GA (Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64)

Tags: ios, 64-bit, titanium-mobile, x86-64, titanium-alloy

in order to fulfil [Apple 64-bit requirements](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172014b) for apps, I've just update an app to Titanium SDK 3.5.0.GA. The app was previously running on 3.4.1.GA, and doing it fine.

Now, once I compile for IOS I'm getting this error stack:

```
[TRACE] Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
[TRACE]   "_TiDebuggerStart", referenced from:
[TRACE]       -[TiApp boot] in TiApp.o
[TRACE]   "_TiDebuggerStop", referenced from:
[TRACE]       -[TiApp dealloc] in TiApp.o
[TRACE]   "_TiProfilerStart", referenced from:
[TRACE]       -[TiApp boot] in TiApp.o
[TRACE]   "_TiDebuggerLogMessage", referenced from:
[TRACE]       _TiLogMessage in TiBase.o
[TRACE]       -[APIModule logMessage:severity:] in APIModule.o
[TRACE]   "_TiDebuggerEndScript", referenced from:
[TRACE]       -[KrollBridge evalFileOnThread:context:] in KrollBridge.o
[TRACE]       -[KrollBridge require:path:] in KrollBridge.o
[TRACE]   "_TiDebuggerCreate", referenced from:
[TRACE]       -[KrollContext main] in KrollContext.o
[TRACE]   "_TiProfilerEnable", referenced from:
[TRACE]       -[KrollContext main] in KrollContext.o
[TRACE]   "_TiDebuggerDestroy", referenced from:
[TRACE]       -[KrollContext stop] in KrollContext.o
[TRACE]   "_TiDebuggerBeginScript", referenced from:
[TRACE]       -[KrollBridge evalFileOnThread:context:] in KrollBridge.o
[TRACE]       -[KrollBridge require:path:] in KrollBridge.o
[TRACE] ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
[TRACE] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[ERROR] ** BUILD FAILED **
[ERROR] The following build commands failed:
[ERROR]         Ld build/QuickIcons.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyAPP-universal.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyAPP normal i386
[ERROR]         Ld build/QuickIcons.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyAPP-universal.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MyAPP normal x86_64
[ERROR] (2 failures)
```

Everything still works fine for Android.

I red it could be due to modules, I'm using only `Ti.Facebook` and `Ti.Cloud`.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try running it on an iPhone 6 simulator? That worked for me, after I had the same problem trying to run it on the iPhone 5s simulator.

Answer (score 0):

What are the modules are those that are using in your application? Facebook is here -> http://gitt.io/search?q=%20architectures%3Ax86_64;

Ti.Cloud apparently still not supported; also possibly has something to revise your code :)

Best,
Alberto

Comment: I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ti-64 to detect the broken module, it came out that I have 3 versions of ti.facebook, one being unsuitable for 64bit. Thanks

Comment: Ti-64 Is Cool. You can use Ti.Facebook version 3.2.0.

Comment: By the way, you added or you modified something in the TiApp.xml to identify changing versions 3.5.0.GA or just made a rebuild of your app.

Best,
Alberto

Comment: I manually switch from 3.4.1.GA to 3.5.0.GA. I have Ti.Facebook 3.2.0 installed, but it fails address the correct version, it seems. I'm trying `gittio install facebook` but I'm addressing some problems...
It's definitely monday ;)

Comment: Sometimes it is definitely because it's Monday; I'm kidding. By the way, what device you are using for this test? iPhone 5S, 6, 6 ++?.

Best,
Alberto